# If I update more than one fields in an update using firestore, how many read operation that it is counted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document that has 20 fields. if I update 3 fields in a document using this code:

```
let cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

let updateSingle = cityRef.update({
   capital: true, 
   population: 1000000,
   country: "USA"
});
```

will I get charged for one single write or will I be charge for 3 writes ?

Comment: Updates are always on document read or write within the collection. If you are getting into one document, that is 1 count. In your case, it is just one write operation.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @r_batra! :)

Comment: so no matter how many field I update in a document as long as it is used only one .update() then it will be counted as 1 write operation ? because I will use a lot of update like this in my app

Comment: That is correct. It counts the number of documents you write, not the number of fields you write.